# Draw a line segment tangent to an SMA line

Tags: pine-script

How to draw a line segment that is tangent to an SMA line for trends in pine script for tradingview.

What I would really love is a small line segment of about 5 candles long, centered on current candle, that shows a tangent line of the current candle sma5.

A very help fellow here gave me a code to draw a line from ohlc4 from one candle back to the ohlc4 of a candle 5 candles back. I played with it to try and get something similar to what I am trying to accomplish, but I am just not able to get it right.

```
//@version=4
study("Lookback Trend SMA", overlay=true)
LB1 = input(5, title="Look back candles")
sma4 = sma(close, 1)
sma5 = sma(close, LB1)
var line    myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, color = color.yellow, width = 2)
if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index[1],  sma4[1])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index[LB1], sma5[LB1])
```

I apologize for my butcher job to his eloquent code. But I really am trying to learn, rather than have to bother others with what is probably something simple. But I have been working on it for a few days and havent figured it out.

I appreciate all help, thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to limit it to 5 bars, without resorting to angle calculations, but here's a quick-and-dirty way to mimic a tangent with a line that extends left.
It basically just takes the 2 latest `sma5` values and draws a (left extended) line through them.

```
//@version=4
study("Lookback Trend SMA", "LT", overlay=true)

LB1 = input(5, title="Look back candles")

var line    myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, color = color.yellow, width = 2, extend=extend.left)

sma5 = sma(close, LB1)

if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index[1], sma5[1])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index, sma5)

plot(sma5, "sma5", color.blue)
```